# x11 - can't move mouse cursor with nouveau, xev still reports movement

Tags: xorg, nouveau, drm, xcursor

I am currently using the nouveau DRM with fallback `xf86-video-modesetting` drivers on arch linux with a GTX 1080. I am currently experiencing an issue in x.org where my mouse will be stuck at the position on the top left of my monitor about 10 pixels from (0,0). When I run `xev -root`, I still see mouse movement registered and I can see the mouse cursor actually change (from cursor to I-bone to glove) as it should depending on what it's "hovering" over. The mouse itself is still usable as I can click/right click things just as normal (I will have to "guess" the mouse position based on what text is selected, what window is in focus from mouse hover, etc).

Xorg.0.log: http://pastebin.com/RqurVjz0

```
$lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   98304  3
snd_usb_audio         155648  2
mousedev               20480  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        28672  1 snd_usb_audio
joydev                 20480  0
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
cfg80211              495616  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    65536  1 vfat
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             188416  0
kvm                   516096  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
asus_wmi               24576  1 eeepc_wmi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
cryptd                 20480  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
led_class              16384  2 asus_wmi,input_leds
intel_cstate           16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
nouveau              1523712  2
psmouse               126976  0
ttm                    86016  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 nouveau
drm                   294912  5 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_codec_realtek    69632  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    86016  1 mei_me
e1000e                229376  0
snd_hda_intel          32768  5
snd_hda_codec         106496  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
i2c_i801               24576  0
snd_pcm                90112  6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69632  25 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hci_uart               81920  0
shpchp                 32768  0
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
fan                    16384  0
bluetooth             487424  4 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,btbcm
thermal                20480  0
battery                20480  0
rfkill                 20480  4 asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
i2c_hid                20480  0
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
evdev                  24576  13
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           53248  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    36864  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               28672  1 ip_tables
ext4                  524288  1
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
jbd2                   90112  1 ext4
fscrypto               24576  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  2 ext4
sd_mod                 36864  3
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   114688  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            61440  1 uas
serio_raw              16384  0
atkbd                  24576  0
libps2                 16384  2 atkbd,psmouse
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                28672  1 ahci
xhci_pci               16384  0
libata                208896  2 ahci,libahci
xhci_hcd              172032  1 xhci_pci
usbcore               208896  7 usbhid,snd_usb_audio,usb_storage,xhci_pci,snd_usbmidi_lib,uas,xhci_hcd
scsi_mod              159744  4 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
i8042                  28672  0
serio                  20480  6 serio_raw,atkbd,psmouse,i8042
wmi                    16384  3 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  36864  2 asus_wmi,nouveau
button                 16384  1 nouveau
```

I can have an empty xorg.conf or the xorg.conf configured by the nvidia DRM, so this is negligible. However, I will go ahead and post my xorg.conf

```
$cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak 
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 370.28  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-17)  Thu Sep  1 20:22:52 PDT 2016


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"

EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    #Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Here's the output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
```

**EDIT:** This behavior is actually the same in a vanilla arch install without `nvidia` drivers.